# Difficulty in adding alert to Pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, alerts

I am fairly new to coding. I stumbled across a script to which I'd like to add an alert when the '▲' appear on the chart. I could not figure it out for the past couple days so I was wondering - is this possible and if yes how? If you have any ideas on how to do it or any videos that could help me figure it out please let me know. Here is a link to the script and below is a picture of it.

https://www.tradingview.com/script/amRCTgFw-Nadaraya-Watson-Estimator-LUX/

The picture is the whole script

[image: The picture is the whole script]

Comment: This script repaints like crazy. Did you know that?

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment @Bjorgum, yes unfortunately it repaints. That's one of the reasons why I thought an alert would be great to see how well the script works to track it. My coding is just not good enough to get rid of the repainting - if that's even possible? I just started learning and would be thankful for any help ideas you have concerning the alerts and repainting!!

Comment: Hi @Bjorgum if I would add this:

// Get user input
res = input(title="Timeframe", type=input.resolution, defval="D")
// Create non-repainting security function
rp_security(_symbol, _res, _src) => security(_symbol, _res, _src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0]) 

to the beginning of the script under line 3 (study) would this prevent the repainting?
Sorry for all the questions.. I am a little lost with this right now.